# Cython code : Python.h no such file or directory

Tags: python, c, linux, ubuntu, cython

when I generate C code from python3 code with `cython3` and try to compile with gcc the resulting code, I get this error : `test.c:4:20: fatal error: Python.h: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type` .

I looked over the web for this error, and all the answer were about installing `python2-dev` or `python3-dev` , but I already have this two installed in my computer. I don't only have these two, but I have `python3.4-dev` and `python3.5-dev` too.

So can anyone give me the solution to this error.

PS : I am using Ubuntu 15.10 with linux version > 4 .

Comment: What does `apt-cache policy python-dev` say?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should compile using the appropriate paths, like this...

```
$ gcc -o test test.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs python3`
```

What happened before is that you weren't including the appropiate include paths (retrieved by `pkg-config --cflags`) and library/linking paths (retrieved by `pkg-config --libs`). Including both, your program should be able to compile and link.

Comment: Note that in practice it is often easier to [configure Setuptools](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/source_files_and_compilation.html) than to try and run gcc by hand (Cython.org appears to be down, so [here's the Google cache](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:HV_disJcZycJ:docs.cython.org/src/userguide/source_files_and_compilation.html+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us)).